# Python 3.4 :While loop not looping

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop, infinite-loop

Python loop isn't wanting to loop back if the user's guess is greater than or less than the randomly generated value. It either exits the loop or creates an infinite loop. Where am I going wrong?

```
import random

correct = random.randint(1, 100)
tries = 1
inputcheck = True
print("Hey there! I am thinking of a numer between 1 and 100!")
while inputcheck:
    guess = input("Try to guess the number! " )
    #here is where we need to make the try statement
    try:
        guess = int(guess)
    except ValueError:
        print("That isn't a number!")
        continue
    if 0 <= guess <= 100:
        inputcheck = False
    else:
        print("Choose a number in the range!")
        continue
    if guess == correct:
        print("You got it!")
        print("It took you {} tries!".format(tries))
        inputcheck = False
    if guess > correct:
        print("You guessed too high!")
        tries = tries + 1
    if guess < correct:
        print("You guessed too low!")
        tries = tries + 1

    if tries >= 7:
        print("Sorry, you only have  7 guesses...")
        keepGoing = False
```

Comment: Your loop is on `inputcheck`, which you set to `False` in the `if 0 <= guess <= 100` block. Why do you expect it to keep running if you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
if 0 <= guess <= 100:
    inputcheck = False
```

This will terminate the loop whenever the user enters a number between 0 and 100. You can rewrite this part as:

```
if not 0 <= guess <= 100:
    print("Choose a number in the range!")
    continue
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped a bunch. I can't believed I overlooked that!

Answer (score 1):

The correct code is below:

```
import random

correct = random.randint(1, 100)
tries = 1
inputcheck = True
print("Hey there! I am thinking of a numer between 1 and 100!")
while inputcheck:
    guess = input("Try to guess the number! " )
    #here is where we need to make the try statement
    try:
        guess = int(guess)
    except ValueError:
        print("That isn't a number!")
        continue
    if 0 > guess or guess > 100:
        print("Choose a number in the range!")
        continue
    if guess == correct:
        print("You got it!")
        print("It took you {} tries!".format(tries))
        inputcheck = False
    if guess > correct:
        print("You guessed too high!")
        tries = tries + 1
    if guess < correct:
        print("You guessed too low!")
        tries = tries + 1
    if tries > 7:
        print("Sorry, you only have  7 guesses...")
        inputcheck = False
```

The problem here was that you were setting `inputcheck` to False when the value of `guess` was in between 0 and 100. This changed the value of while to `False` and the loop was exiting since while wasn't `True` anymore.

Also, you should change the last `if` case in the while loop since this now fixes the case of running indefinitely:

```
if tries > 7:
    print("Sorry, you only have  7 guesses...")
    inputcheck = False
```

Comment: To the downvoter: Please do point out what is wrong with the answer